# Correlated Wiener processes of different factors

Tags: correlation, heston, cholesky

I'm relatively new in this field, so I have a couple of points that I need to clarify.

I would like to know how I can estimate the correlation matrix necessary to implement a Cholesky decomposition for a model that has two different sources of risk.

Let's take for example an Heston model where we have two Brownian motions, $W_{s}$ and $W_{v}$.

In the case of a portfolio composed by two stocks, in order to be able to simulate correlated paths:

1. How do I estimate the correlation matrix of the variance process for the two stocks? Moving average std or other methods?
2. Because in Heston model $W_{s}$ and $W_{v}$ are correlated, so that we have  $\rho_{1}=corr(W_{1s},W_{1v})$ for the first asset and $\rho_{2}=corr(W_{2s},W_{2v})$ for the second asset, do I have to get two different matrixes of dimension $2\times2$ (one for each stock) or one matrix of dimension $4\times4$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please take a look at [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27062/itoprocess-function/27110#27110) and [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27068/share-experiences-preferably-the-surprising-ones-with-using-itoprocess/27711#27711).

Answer (score 2):

You need to obtain a $4 \times 4$ correlation matrix.  As you effectively observe, you have four random processes driving the system, with $i \in 1,2$

$$
\frac{dS_i}{S_i} = \mu_i dt + \sqrt{v_i} dW_{Si} \\
dv_i = \kappa(\bar{v}_{i}-v_i) dt + \xi \sqrt{v_i} dW_{vi}
$$

Each of the $W_{ji},j\in\{S,v\},i\in 1,2$ is a brownian motion correlated with the others, with coefficient $\rho_{i_1,j_1}^{i_2,j_2}$.

Because $v$ is not observed, you cannot work backwards from historical market data to values of $W_{ji}$, so you cannot obtain correlations in the "usual" manner.

You can estimate the parameters of each individual model (including the $\rho_{i,j_1}^{i,j_2}$ values) either by calibrating to historical time series data or to the options markets (depending on your application).  This leaves you with a set of cross correlations $\rho_{i_1,j_1}^{i_2,j_2},i_1\neq i_2$ to estimate, and you probably lack basket options to calibrate them from.

You can calibrate these historically, perhaps using [Gibbs Sampling](http://web.mit.edu/~wingated/www/introductions/mcmc-gibbs-intro.pdf%E2%80%8E) due to the complexity of the joint terminal distribution.  Alternatively, you could just go with estimates based on simple relationships.  That is, set

$$
\rho_{1,S}^{2,S} = \text{Corr}\left( \text{Ret}(\{S_1\}), \text{Ret}(\{S_2\}) \right)\\
\rho_{1,v}^{2,v} = \text{Corr}\left( \left\{\sigma_1^{\text{implied}}\right\}, \left\{\sigma_2^{\text{implied}}\right\} \right) \\
\rho_{1,S}^{2,v} = \rho_{1,v}^{2,S} = 0
$$

You are unlikely (in my opinion) to be making estimation errors larger than your [model errors](http://www.actuaries.org.uk/sites/all/files/documents/pdf/0461-0469.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer. Actually I though to use a similar method but using the historical returns and calculating the rolling volatility, obtaining a backward measure of the correlation.

One more question: With $corr(\{\sigma_{1}^{implied}\},\{\sigma_{2}^{implied}])$ do you mean a correlation calculated from a chain of options (i.e. ATM for every maturity available for example) or other type of implied volatilities?

Then, adding all these terms together, and leaving 0 on the cross correlations, it is possible that the final correlation matrix is not positive definite. What do you think about?

Comment: This is a comment (or another question), not an answer.